# How do you read an array into a matplotlib graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I've loaded a dataset of x and y values from a txt file

```
dataset = np.loadtxt("data")
```

there are about 100 points in there

when I tried to use

```
plt.scatter(dataset[0], dataset[1], marker='+', s=500, c='b')
```

I got two points which don't correlate to any x and y values, I'm using [0] [1] because those should be the x and y values correct?

keep in mind when I print the data set I get the following

```
[[ 1 , 2], 
[ 2, 3], 
[ 4, 5]]
```

that's not all of them but you get the idea I have an array of arrays so when I type `dataset[0]` or `dataset[1]` am I actually just taking an array and matplotlib is trying to interpret two arrays into a point?

Pic of the scatter plot I get:

[image: Pic of the scatter plot I get]

Comment: If your data set is really as shown.  Then you would get 2 points.  dataset[0] would be [1,2] and dataset[1] would be [2,3]   First input to scatter is "x" coordinates `dataset[0]`, second is y... so you should see 2 points at (1,2) and (2,3).  We would need to see a more full version of what your data really looks like to help more

Comment: the points I put up were just to demonstrate how the data was set up because I felt that maybe that had something to do with it? as I said I actually have 100 x and y variables so I can't list them all.

Comment: What I am saying is if your data is really nx2 as show then there is no way you will get 3 points plotted with the command you have shows.   So something doesn't makes sense in your questions and example data.

Comment: I included a pic of what I am getting on my scatterplot, also I realise you were right and I was wrong I was getting two points I confused them because I did multiple scatter plots on the same graph

Comment: See the answer below.  You are not indexing the dataset correctly to get the first and second columns

Comment: Yeah that was the problem thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help you for certain with your problem without some more information.  However, if your data is really Nx2  and you want to plot N pairs of points you would do this.

The `dataset[:,0]` portion will get the first column and use those values for `x`,  `dataset [:,1]` will get the second column and use those for `y`

```
dataset = np.array([[ 1 , 2], [ 2, 3], [ 4, 5]])
Out: 
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5]])

plt.scatter(dataset[:,0], dataset[:,1], marker='+', s=500, c='b')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I was ultimately trying something similar to you but I went too deep in that because I thought there was arrays in arrays I had to break them apart. if that makes sense?

Comment: @Livingstone  If this answered your question then consider accepting the solution.  Thanks